# How to cancel repeated alarm set for every day

Tags: android, alarm

I'm working on calendar events .

When adding events to the calendar  I'm creating an alert using alarm manager

this is working fine.

I need to cancel the alert for that particular event while deleting event.

I'm setting alarm like this.

```
AlarmManager amgr=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Intent intent=new Intent(AmdAddEvent.this, RepeatingAlarmReceiver.class);
intent.putExtra("time", mAlarmTime);
PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AmdAddEvent.this,(int) mAlarmTime,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);


amgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, mAlarmTime,AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

how to cancel alert while deleting event.

Please help me regarding this

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

```
amgr.cancel(Pending Intent); ,
```

you can use this to cancel the pending alarm event.

[AlaramManager Cancel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel%28android.app.PendingIntent%29)

Answer (score 0):

If you are coding for deleting event in another class,then you need to create an intent again with the same id(in your case,it is `(int) mAlarmTime`)and then you can cancel the specific alarm intent.else you can just use cancel() of alarmManager oject. Enter this lines of code where you delete the alarm event:

```
try
{       
    Intent intent=new Intent(AmdAddEvent.this, RepeatingAlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("time", mAlarmTime);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AmdAddEvent.this,(int) mAlarmTime,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    amgr.cancel(pendingIntent);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

Comment: i given same lines of code for AMDDeleteEvent class but it is not working still alert is coming eventhough i have canceled the alarm

Comment: Have you checked the id attached to each alarm manager intent?? it must be unique if you are using multiple alarm event.        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AmdAddEvent.this,alarmIntentId,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

Comment: And yes,be sure you are not writing amgr.setRepeating.... after the lines of code i have given. Instead,you must use amgr.cancel(pendingIntent)

Comment: I didn't use amgr.setRepeating for deleting event.what i'm doing is that while setting alarm i'm stroing alarmintentid into the database and while deleting the event i'm getting the same intent id and passing same alamintentid to the  pendingIntent eventhugh i'm not succeded to cancel the alarm still alert is coming.i don't know where i'm doing wrong. Thanks for the reply hiral

Comment: @dhriti: Try to trace the id you use to set alarm.Is it the same id you are using to cancel it when deleting that particular alarm? problem must be there only.else this is working perfect in my project.and i do the same thing as you did. And also provide your edited code in the question.so that we can try finding the problem.

Comment: As you said it may be problem with id only.i will try to sort it out.thanks for the great help.

Comment: i have a doubt can u please help me .Actually i have  given alarmtime as a intentId ofcourse alarmtime differs for each intent so alarmintentid is unique.can we give some other intent id other than alarmtime if so how to give.

Comment: well,this is what you are wrong at. It is not good practice to use it as alarm id. instead,you can use the id of a row in your table,for which you are setting up an alarm. ex:if you are setting alarm for different events set in your database in a table with name and other details,you should use _id of an event to set alarm for that particular event. hope,it is clear now.

Comment: and one more thing instead of AMDAddEvent.this i given AMDUpdateEvent.this because i'm calling from this class is it correct only aaaaaaaaa

Comment: @dhriti: Yup,That is not a problem. it is fine.

Comment: Actually i'm storing event data to the database and simultaneously i'm settinga alarm how to get rowid.rowid automatically set in the database na

Comment: Insert a record first and then set an alarm. You would get a long variable on insertion of record in database,which actually gives you the _id given to the lastly inserted data. Eg: long id=sqdb.insert(...);

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT USE getBroadcast(), method it will not work.

Use the following code to create an alarm to create an activity:

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(RemindingService.this, day, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT |PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Use the following code to cancel the alarm anytime:

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(RemindingService.this, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE|PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
if(pendingIntent != null) {
alarmMgr.cancel(pendingIntent);
   pendingIntent.cancel();  
}
```

This is will tested and it is working well.